# Simple refresh of LIberty Websphere Sphere Application server 16, with enterpriseApplication

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I hear I can use the dropins directory to hot deploy code.  But let's say I want to use the apps directory and a preconfigured application.  For example, I downloaded the standard liberty jar version 16.  And using the 'apps' directory under my server.config directory, I was able to add a EAR to that directory.  Also, I added the following configuration my server.xml:

Based on this, I am using a class loaded directory and a enterpriseApplication entry, this configuration will load when I start and stop the server, but I can't figure out how to ensure this configuration for hot deployment.  E.g. when I change the ear, I was hoping the server would restart automatically and/or reload the classes.

I wish there were a 'scan' attribute for the enterpriseApplication.

I used the 'applicationMonitor' setting but didn't recognize my enterpiseApplication directory and did not load.  That configuration seems to only recognize the dropins.

I tried to use the dropins but it didn't work because I was using a shared library.  I can't put all of the jars in one EAR.

```
   <library id="Alexandria">
                <fileset dir="/usr/local/pfs/dist/wlp/usr/servers/rest/mylib/Alexandria" includes="*.jar" scanInterval="20s" />
        </library>

    <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <enterpriseApplication location="napolEA.ear" name="MyApp">
                <classloader privateLibraryRef="Alexandria" />
    </enterpriseApplication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for "hot deploying" code with Liberty is with WebSphere Developer Tools (WDT) eclipse plugin: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/

Regarding a "scan" attribute for your application: any `<application>`, `<webApplication>`, or `<enterpriseApplication>` scanning is controlled by the `<applicationMonitor>` element. By default, it's configuration is:

```
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="polled" pollingRate="500ms"/>
```

So, the configuration should be scanning for app updates every 500ms.

Comment: Does it scan for both the "enterpriseApplication" and "dropins".  I notice if I dropin a new war in the dropins directory, that gets picked up, code changes are reflected.  Even the documentation mentions dropins.  With the path I specify by enterpriseApplication, I am not noticing changes picked up.

Comment: A dropin application just means that it is an application with no config in server.xml. An enterprise application (ear) could also be a "dropin" application. You can try it by putting your ear in the dropins folder

Comment: And if you are wondering how to apply a shared lib to an dropin application, you can do so by changing your id="Alexandria" library to be id="global" instead.

Comment: I tried putting the ear in the dropins directory but the shared classpath reference fails. OK, just saw the global note. Are you on the IBM team, seems like only insiders would know what.

Comment: The global shared library concept is documented, but not many people know about it. Basically the library with id="global" is available to all apps

Comment: One more question, you mean put the jars in a global directory or just call the id to global?   And/or copy the jars to global and then use the global classpath as a reference.

Comment: just change the id to global will be enough. See this doc for more info: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html